# How many triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that $xyz,(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$ quadratic residues?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $x,y,z\in\{2,\dots,p-1\}$. How many triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ distinct and $xyz,(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$ quadratic residues modulo $p$?

P/s: I really want to count $(x,y,z)$ such that
$\begin{cases}
ab\equiv x\pmod{p}\\
bc\equiv y\pmod{p}\\
ca\equiv z\pmod{p}
\end{cases}$
and 
$\begin{cases}
a'b'\equiv 1-x\pmod{p}\\
b'c'\equiv 1-y\pmod{p}\\
c'a'\equiv 1-z\pmod{p}
\end{cases}$
have root $a,b,c,a',b',c'$.

Comment: Why were you interested to ask this question? Where does it come from?

Comment: I had a problem when I want to count roots of modulo equation system on integer.

Comment: And? Please add the full context in your question.

Comment: Any reason to expect a pleasant, closed, answer?  What's the answer for, say, $p≤11$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a closed form formula for this, and here is how I would do to get such a formula.

1. Using Legendre symbol, we can restate that we need $x, y, z$ satisfying $$\left(\frac{xyz}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}{p}\right) = 1.$$ Note that the second term is the same as $$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\left(\frac{(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)}{p}\right).$$
2. Show that among $x \in \{2, \cdots, p-1\}$, there are $(p-3)/2$ quadratic residues and $(p-1)/2$ quadratic non-residues.
3. For $(a, b) = (\pm 1, \pm 1)$, you need to count in the four cases, the number of $x$ satisfying $\left(\frac{x}{p}\right) = a, \quad \left(\frac{x-1}{p}\right) = b$.
4. Try to exhaust all the combination of $$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right), \left(\frac{1-x}{p}\right), \left(\frac{y}{p}\right), \left(\frac{1-y}{p}\right), \left(\frac{z}{p}\right), \left(\frac{1-z}{p}\right)$$ which gives you the correct possible Lenendre symbols, and sum them all.

Step 1 and 2 only involves basic properties of Legengre symbols; step 4 is brutal, but possible (maybe you need lots of symmetries to simplify your calculations). So below we deal only with step 3.

The key fact will be the following:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^p \left(\frac{x(x-1)}{p}\right) = -1.$$

The standard way to see this is to observe that $$\sum_{i=1}^p \left(1+\left(\frac{x(x-1)}{p}\right) \right)$$ is the number of pair $(x,y) \in \mathbb F_p$ (i.e. under modulo $p$ arithmetic) such that $y^2 = x(x-1)$. Indeed there are $p-1$ of them.

The reason is, it is obvious that $(0,0)$ is a pair, and is the only one satisfying $x = 0$.

For each $\lambda \in \mathbb F_p$, consider the intersection of $y^2 = x(x-1)$ and $y = \lambda x$. One can show that each $\lambda \neq \pm 1$ gives one new solution, and each solution not equals to $(0,0)$ comes in this way.

So you will see that within $x \in \{2, \cdots, p-1\}$, $(p-3)/2$ of them satisfies $\left(\frac{x(x-1)}p\right) = 1$ and $(p-1)/2$ of them satisfies $\left(\frac{x(x-1)}p\right) = -1$. In other words, if you write down $\left(\frac 1p\right), \cdots \left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)$ in a row, they changed sign $(p-1)/2$ times.

As you know that $\left(\frac 1p\right) = 1$ and $\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$, this will tell you how among the changes of signs, how many times it changed from $1$ to $-1$ and how many times in the other direction. This will imply a complete answer to step 3.